# On the nature of indefiniteness of a function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Consider a function $f:(0,\infty)\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (not necessarily continuous) satisfying the following conditions.

1. $f$ is strictly increasing, and
2. For each sequence $\{\alpha_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of positive numbers, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\alpha_n=0$ if and only if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(\alpha_n)=-\infty$.

**Claim:** $f(0)=-\infty$

Let $F$ be the extended function of $f$ to the domain $[0,\infty)$. Let if possible, $F(0)=\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Consider $\{a_n\}$, a decreasing sequence of positive numbers with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=0$, then by condition (2), we can find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$F(a_n)<F(0),\quad\text{for all } n\geq N,$$
contradicting the fact that $f$ (and hence $F$) is strictly increasing.

Thus the only possibilities are the indeterminates $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. It can't be $+\infty$ by condition (1) and hence $F(0)=-\infty$ is the only choice for the extension of $f$ on $[0,\infty)$, which seems to point that $F=f$.

Can we then write $f(0)=-\infty$?

Comment: Your ideas are all OK but we cannot even write $f(0)$ since $0$ is not in the domain. What your argument proves is $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x)=-\infty$. You should also mention explicitly that $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x)$ exists an an extended real number because of monotonicity.

Comment: There is no such word as "indefinity".

Comment: @GerryMyerson At a loss for words to describe the problem, I came up with it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The symbol $\tan\frac{\pi}{2}=+\infty$ is a way of saying $\tan x$ is not defined at the point $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$. And since we write $x<+\infty$ to denote finite real numbers, can we write $x<+\infty=\tan\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Is it not another way of writing the condition given in the question?

Comment: One problem with writing $\tan(\pi/2)=+\infty$ is that the same logic which supports it supports equally writing $\tan(\pi/2)=-\infty$, which leaves you with $\infty=-\infty$.